# Kernel Panic when booting ubuntu 12.04 LTS in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I try to run it in Virtualbox 4.3.6 but it says: Kernel panic : attempted to kill init!
Can anyone help me???

Comment: As you have accepted the answer, can you please add what exactly worked for you out of all those options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things you could try:

1. Increase the Memory and Video Memory available to the VM
2. Download a fresh ISO using a torrent, that way you can guarantee it won't be corrupt. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads
3. Delete the VM and create a fresh one with the default options.
4. Try disabling the USB Controller, the Network Adapter, and the Audio to see if that helps.
5. Look at options like VT-X/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX and IO APIC and the Chipset. Switching some of these may sometimes help.