# What is this error "end kernel panic" (while trying to install virtual ubuntu machine)

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I know my iso file is good because I've installed it on a few different laptops, but when I tried installing it in virtual box it freezes on this screen:
[image: frozen virtual box]

This is my first time trying to set up a virtual machine. I followed this http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/hacking-tutorial/10-steps-how-to-create-kali-linux-virtual-machine-in-virtual-box/#sthash.FNC0pQz9.dpbs tutorial, except that I used my iso from before instead of kali whatever.

So far [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init) is the most relevant previously asked question I've found on askubuntu.com, or elsewhere. But it seems to be about a previously installed OS.

Update: Maybe it's not frozen.. I've had it open for like an hour and it finally printed out a few more lines..
[image]

Comment: "end Kernel panic" - what happens when my popcorn is finished! ;) All joking aside, you didn't mention what version of Ubuntu you are using as a virtual machine. 64 bit or 32 bit? What is your host OS? What is your processor (Intel/AMD)? Also, it would be helpful if you stated what settings in your virtual machine you used. Especially if you have set the VT-d/x (hardware passthrough). There could be so many reasons for the Kernel panic. Check this post to see if it is helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/406575/kernel-panic-when-booting-ubuntu-12-04-lts-in-virtualbox/406614

Comment: Tip: I've only got errors like that on the period when my computer was super unstable and constantly crashed, even one time i saw the BIOS looping and it just broken. The virtual machine may be incompatible or super unstable.

Comment: Update: I downloaded a 64 bit version and restarted my computer and created a new virtual machine with even more ram (I've only got four gigs and I gave the last one two), and tried installing the 64 bit. . And so far it seems to be working although very slowly.

Comment: Can't get many details now because it's very hard to even move the mouse.. But the host os is Windows 10 I think my processor is 1ghz amd, I have no idea what a hardware pas through is

Comment: Hardware pass through is when the virtual machine communicates directly with parts of your hardware, without having to go through the 'virtual' layers. This usually speeds things up and makes some specific hardware components available. That being said you usually see better implementation on the 'server' class of processors. Also, running a virtual machine is very taxing for the host machine, especially if you assign too many resources to the guest on a host that is underpowered... which seems to be the case with your machine (1 Ghz AMD, 4GB RAM).

Answer (score 2):

select that machine settings > system> processor then change number of processors to at least 2

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue, and after many trials, I remembered my BIOS did not have virtualization enabled. After I enabled this option in BIOS setup, everything is working fine. (Intel does not have an option for that)

Comment: Make sure you enabled virtualization in your BIOS. It worked for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

This panic screen — which you have not transcribed in full in your question but really should so that the text will be indexed and people will find it in the future — is the panic screen that results when process #1 exits after not handling signal #4 (illegal instruction).

As I just explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/706543/43344 , some of the important information has scrolled off your screen, namely the `Comm:` line that tells us what program was running as process #1.  It could be `Comm: sh`, or `Comm: init`, or even `Comm: run-init` as in the AskUbuntu question that you linked to in your question.

You need to find out what was printed that has scrolled off the top of your screen.  Without it, you cannot fully diagnose this problem beyond *some unknown program* did *something unknown* that caused an illegal instruction signal to be raised.  Persuading the boot loader to switch the screen into, say, 50 line mode would be one way of doing this.  Configuring VirtualBox with an appropriate serial device and bootstrapping with a serial console would be another.

The text that was printed later on is a red herring, by the way.  That's just the interrupt-driven "entropy collection" in your kernel finally picking up enough "randomness".  Your kernel is sitting spinning in an endless loop because of the panic.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195978/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197472/5132