# Kernel Panic when setting up Ubuntu 16.04 with VirtualBox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 16.04

FIRST NOTE: I tried the solution proposed by [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/406614/534528), but it did not work. Besides, the fact that I've reinstalled Windows recently could (or could not) make my situation a little different.

Some months ago, I installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox and it went fine. But I recently formatted my disk and reinstalled Windows 7. So I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox as before. Now though, I get this Kernel Panic message as I'm trying to install the 'i386 Desktop' version:

[image]

Here's my VM's configuration:

[image]

The 64-bit version of Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work ; it says it can't detect my 64-bit CPU (guess VirtualBox is made only for 32-bit Ubuntu). I've tried installing the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04.4, but the same kernel panic message appeared. I've also tried the tips from [this answer to a similar topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/406614/534528), but it didn't work.

I know little about OSs, so I'm sort of stuck here. I don't know if the fact that I reinstalled Windows 7 recently is relevant. I'll provide the files you ask for (but please indicate clearly how I can find them).

Comment: Try with 64bit VirtualBox. My guess is that you've downloaded VBox 32bit version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel Panic when booting ubuntu 12.04 LTS in virtualbox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406575/kernel-panic-when-booting-ubuntu-12-04-lts-in-virtualbox)

Comment: @Windowsinsider BoomTech As I stated at the end of my question, I saw that thread, but it didn't work.

Comment: @ForceMagic As you suggested, I've uninstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox from Oracle's website, rather than VirtualBox's. There is apparently only 1 version of VirtualBox for Windows, which does both x86 and x64. So I basically reinstalled the same software I had before. I then made a new Ubuntu VM, but it didn't help. I still get the same panic error.

Comment: "The 64-bit version of Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work"
That's weird... I have the 64-bit version working fine on VirtualBox over here. I'm pretty sure the guest is limited by the host, so can you confirm you've installed Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I do have Windows 7 64-bit running on my computer. I went here to download VB (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html), and, as you can see, there is only 1 version of VB for Windows, for both 32-bit and 64-bit hosts.