# kernel panic error installing ubuntu 16.04 server in virtualbox 5.1.22 on windows 7

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install ubuntu server on my virtualbox vm but I get this error after I choose english as my language and then install ubuntu server. My logs do not seem to be giving me anything helpful. How can I get past this error so I can install ubuntu 16.04?

[image: kernel panic error]

Comment: Is your VM set well with enough space?

Comment: I gave it 512MB of ram and 10GB of space. I am planning to deploy my local vm settings to a remote server eventually which will also have 512MB ram and 20GB of space on digital ocean

Comment: I upped to 2GB of ram and got the same error still

Comment: Please 10GB of space isn't enough at least 20 to 30GB should do...

Comment: Duplicate of this (also unanswered) question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/762077/kernel-panic-when-setting-up-ubuntu-16-04-with-virtualbox

Comment: Ubuntu Server claims to be able to install on just 1.5 GB of disk space.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Server_.28CLI.29_Installation - so I don't think the disk size is the issue.  I've installed it on an 8 GB disk in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time you've tried to run a VM on this machine?  My shot-in-the dark guess is that you haven't enabled the necessary BIOS settings on the host machine to allow VMs - or you have Hyper-V installed (which is sometimes installed along with other developer tools - like Docker or Visual Studio).  See this post: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=57464

> ```
> 00:00:04.465388 HWACCM: No VT-x or AMD-V CPU extension found. Reason VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED
> ```
>
> You need to make sure that you have enabled hardware virtualization in you bios.
>   Also make sure you do not have Hyper-V installed on the host. If yo do you need to disable it.

I believe they found the above error message by checking the VBox.log file. 
 http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#collect-debug-info

> Every time VirtualBox starts up a VM, a so-called "release log file" is created containing lots of information about the VM configuration and runtime events.
>   The log file is called VBox.log and resides in the VM log file folder. Typically this will be a directory like this:
>
> `$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/{machinename}/Logs`

Checking the contents of that file will hopefully provide more information to point you in the right direction.